# definition of a differentiable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was given the follow definition

> Let $u:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined in a open neighborhood of $(x_{0},y_{0})\in\mathbb{R}^2$. We say that $u$ is differentiable in this neighborhood if:
>
> $$u(x_{0}+\Delta x,y_{0}+\Delta y)=u(x_{0},y_{0})+u_{x}(x_{o},y_{0})\Delta x+u_{y}(x_{0},y_{0})+\epsilon(\Delta x, \Delta y)$$
>
> S.T $$\lim_{(\Delta x, \Delta y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{\epsilon(\Delta x,\Delta y)}{\sqrt{(\Delta x,\Delta y)^2}}=0$$

shouldnt it be $$u(x_{0}+\Delta x,y_{0}+\Delta y)=u(x_{0},y_{0})+u_{x}(x_{o},y_{0})\Delta x+u_{y}(x_{0},y_{0})\color{red}{\Delta y}+\epsilon(\Delta x, \Delta y)$$ ?

Comment: Yes! You're correct

Comment: Typos and mis-writes happen from time to time. Good on you.